# Delete table older than 10 days

Tags: php, mysql

PROBLEM HAS BEEN SOLVED

ANSWER:

```
delete from `[table name]` where [row name] > AddTime( CurTime(), '14400 hour' )
```

This instantly deletes anything that is older than 10 days OLD.

Comment: What you want to delete table or record ?

Comment: surely record, as the syntax the OP provided implies...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

delete from `journal` where journal_date < date_sub(curdate(),interval 5 day)

it can use index on column `journal_date`

but "datediff(now(), journal_date) > 5 " can't use index  on column `journal_date`

Comment: Yes! This one worked!!!! However there is a Slight problem with this, when executed, it deleted all the journals. Including the new ones that were recently posted :/

Comment: Fixed :) so, it turns out that "<" means delete everything LESS than 10 days, but after a small modification of "<" to ">" everything started working. - Thank you very much for this, it worked great :)

Comment: Or not.... it switching it won't delete anything and leaving it 'as is' will delete everything :/

Answer (score 2):

first change string into DATETIME with help of  [`STR_TO_DATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date)

> It takes a string str and a format string format. STR_TO_DATE() returns a **DATETIME**

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE('Wed Nov 21 2012',  '%a %b %d %Y' )

// return 2012-11-21
```

then use [`DATEDIFF`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff)

> DATEDIFF(expr1,expr2)
>
> DATEDIFF() returns **expr1 – expr2** expressed as a value in days from one date to the other.

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(),STR_TO_DATE('Wed Nov 21 2012','%a %b %d %Y'))
//return 8
```

so complete query will be

```
$sql="DELETE FROM `journal` 
      WHERE DATEDIFF(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(),
                     STR_TO_DATE('journal_date','%a %b %d %Y')
                    ) > 5";
```

**Note :** in `STR_TO_DATE` function

use **%d** if you store day of month part with leading Zero ( 01..31 )
  OR use **%e**  if you store day of month part without leading zero (1..31)

Comment: I'm shown with: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'HAVING DATEDIFF(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(),`journal_date`) > 5' at line 1

Comment: I am given: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '%m,%Y')) > 5' at line 1

Comment: Well... it executes without any problems.
But it doesn't delete the record, it remains there.

Comment: Got it, pasted it, didn't change anything, but the records are still there, hm... SQL is weird :/

Comment: first check whether there are records or not. use `SELECT id FROM table WHERE ....(above condition )`

Comment: what nothing changed? what results come when you `select`

Comment: "delete from journal where journal_date < date_sub(curdate(),interval 5 day)" worked, but the problem now is how to make it so it deleted stuff older than 5 days. When executed, it deletes everything.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL date/time functions all work on MySQL DATE and DATETIME values of the format:

```
2012-11-28

2012-11-28 22:16:00
```

If you are actually storing your dates in the format you're specifying, MySQL cannot parse that.

For information on MySQL's date/time functions, see: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html

Comment: Ah, I think this is the right answer. D'oh. Should have read the post more clearly....

Comment: Ah, got it :) Thanks for the clarification, i feel foolish for not even remotely considering said possibility. What command would one need to execute inorder to get: 2012-11-28 22:16:00?

Comment: The MySQL function `NOW()`.

Comment: Thank you duskwulf, and everyone for helping me out. :) 

Have a great year!

Answer (score 1):

You Can Use cron jobs to run specified script

Comment: Well... i was planning on that, but the problem is, without the script executing properly without the use of cron jobs. The script will be useless.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the order of the dates matters. According to [the MySQL reference for `datediff()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff) your dates are backwards, so you are probably only getting negative numbers (hence never more than 5, so no deletions).

Comment: That makes alot more sense haha, so what should i do?

Would the 11-26-2012 8:53:13 format work?

Comment: Actually I might be wrong... I think your dates *are* in the right order. Hmm....

Comment: I'm thrown off myself, i guess the day of the week (Monday, Tuesday, etc..) is what throws off the system from deleting said content?

Comment: I don't think the day of the week is involved at all, I think it just calculates from the date part. Could be a time zone issue, maybe...?

Comment: Ignore my answer! See duskwuff's answer above, I think it's the right one.

Comment: Well, everything is posted on MST (per Godaddy's timestamp)

Answer (score 0):

Use [abs()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_abs) mathematical function to ignore negative date diffrence which is  causing the problem apparently.

```
$sql="delete from `journal` where 
        abs(datediff(now(), STR_TO_DATE('journal_date',  '%a %b %d %Y'))) > 5"
```

Comment: It executes the command, and no problems arise, however the content is still visible. the MYSQL content is not deleted.

Comment: In your question title you have mentioned older than 10 , while in query its older than 5 ...is it ok?

Comment: No problem haha, i have entries from the 21st of november, so that's older than 5 days. But it's not the "older than" part that worries me, it's the command it gives off. I want it to delete the record, not execute properly and remain the same.